# New version creating new file in SharePoint document library

Tags: infopath, event-receivers, versioning

I have SharePoint Document library in which there is InfoPath form. There is one event receiver which works on Item Added event. Version setting for the library is "Create a major version". When I change anything in the form, instead of creating its version, it is creating a new form in the library with the same property except the change. 
Am I missing anything in settings ?

Comment: the old document and the new document created after change have the same name?

Comment: No, new document have different Id. Actually I am renaming the name of Infopath file by event receiver.

Comment: have you checked versioning setings fro document library.

Comment: versioning settings is same as given by Trimantra Software in answer below

Answer (score 0):

The issue with you is that here a new document is uploaded so its not maintaining the versions.

When I was having the same requirement I have achieved this without having event receiver. I followed

1. On load of the InfoPath form I stored the current name of the document in the hidden control on InfoPath.
2. In the submit rule I have used the name of the document stored in the hidden control. And due to this I was able to generate the versioning of the documents and new document was not created.

You can try with this approach once, it solved the requirement.

Also verify once following versioning setting:

[image]

Comment: Other library with same logic is working fine. Only my current library having this issue. Why ? I may missed some version settings or anything else.

Comment: As mentioned in question you have already changed the setting of versioning to "Create a major version". Right?

Comment: Yes, I checked with other working library, versioning settings are same there.

Comment: Is there anything, which controls creating files on version change?

Comment: Yes, I have same settings as you added in image.